# Why the error "function_clause",about erlang,mongodb-erlang,mongodb

Tags: mongodb, erlang

Sorry for my pool Englsih!:-)
My code is here: http://pastebin.com/zus6dGdz
I just want to use the poolboy as my database connection pools,and i use the mongodb-erlang as my driver to communicate with the mongodb.

After running it,from the shell report,I am sure that the mongodb-erlang has created the pools for me

```
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.174.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.178.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.180.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.182.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.184.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.186.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.188.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.190.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.192.0>
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:73
  Database Connection:<0.194.0>
```

and I use the pools like this:
code snap here(in hello_handler.erl,can find it through the the URL above):

```
get_user(Name, Req) ->
  Collection = <<"user">>,
  Selector = {name, Name},
  Worker = poolboy:checkout(?DB_Conn_Pool),
  io:format("***************************Debug*********************************~n  Module:~p ~n  Line:~p ~n  Worker:~p ~n", [?MODULE, ?LINE, Worker]),
  Request = {get_user, {Collection, Selector}},
  UserInfo = gen_server:call(Worker, Request),
  io:format("***************************Debug*********************************~n  Module:~p ~n  Line:~p ~n  UserInfo:~p ~n", [?MODULE, ?LINE, UserInfo]),
  cowboy_req:reply(200, [
    {<<"content-type">>, <<"text/plain">>}
  ], UserInfo, Req).
```

And the the worker process will handle the request in the function handle_call/3 in the db_mongo_handler.erl

code snap:

```
handle_call({get_user, {Collection, Selector}}, _From, #state{connection = Connection} = State) ->
  io:format("***************************Debug*********************************~n
  Module:~p ~n  Line:~p ~n   Handle_call Connection:~p ~n Collection:~p ~n
  Selector:~p ~n Connection is is_pid()? ~p ~n Collection is binary()? ~p ~n",
    [?MODULE, ?LINE, Connection, Collection, Selector, is_pid(Connection), is_binary(Collection)]),
  Cursor = mongo:find(Connection, Collection, Selector),
  io:format("***************************Debug*********************************~n Module:~p ~n  Line:~p ~n
  Cursor:~p ~n", [?MODULE, ?LINE, Cursor]),
  Result = mc_cursor:rest(Cursor),
  [Head | _] = Result,
  {_, _, _, NameValue, _, AgeValue} = Head,
  io:format("***************************Debug*********************************~n Module:~p ~n  Line:~p ~n
  NameValue:~p ~n  AgeValue:~p ~n ", [?MODULE, ?LINE, NameValue, AgeValue]),
  BackData = binary_to_list(<<NameValue/bits, <<":">>/bits, AgeValue/bits>>),
  {reply, BackData, State}.
```

However,it throw the error from this code:

```
Cursor = mongo:find(Connection, Collection, Selector),
```

And the error report is :

```
***************************Debug*********************************

  Module:db_mongo_handler
  Line:104
   Handle_call Connection:<0.194.0>
 Collection:<<"user">>

  Selector:{name,<<"three">>}
 Connection is is_pid()? true
 Collection is binary()? true

=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Feb-2015::14:48:39 ===
** Generic server <0.194.0> terminating
** Last message in was {query,false,false,false,false,<<"user">>,0,0,
                              {name,<<"zhk">>},
                              []}
** When Server state == {state,#Port<0.2666>,
                               {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                     {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                      [],[],[]},
                                     {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                       [],[],[]}}},
                               <<>>,
                               {conn_state,unsafe,master,"user"}}
** Reason for termination ==
** {function_clause,
       [{mongo_protocol,binarize,
            ["user"],
            [{file,"src/core/mongo_protocol.erl"},{line,108}]},
        {mongo_protocol,dbcoll,2,
            [{file,"src/core/mongo_protocol.erl"},{line,44}]},
        {mongo_protocol,put_message,3,
            [{file,"src/core/mongo_protocol.erl"},{line,74}]},
        {mc_worker_logic,'-encode_requests/2-fun-0-',3,
            [{file,"src/connection/mc_worker_logic.erl"},{line,22}]},
        {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1261}]},
        {mc_worker_logic,make_request,3,
            [{file,"src/connection/mc_worker_logic.erl"},{line,73}]},
        {mc_worker,handle_call,3,
            [{file,"src/connection/mc_worker.erl"},{line,75}]},
        {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,607}]}]}
```

I have try this code in erlang shell,the

Cursor = mongo:find(Connection, Collection, Selector),

can run successfully,and i have check the mongodb,the variable type,but finally i have no idea how to solve this problem.Please help me !!:->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the conn_state record,

```
-record(conn_state, {
    write_mode = unsafe :: write_mode(),
    read_mode = master :: read_mode(),
    database :: database()
}).

-type database() :: binary | atom().
```

And you have:

```
{conn_state,unsafe,master,"user"}
```

where user is a string() not a binary or atom.

The mongo_protocol:binarize/1 function only accepts params as binaries or atoms.

Change in hello_erlang.app.src the database value to:

```
{database, user},
```

or 
    {database, <<"user">>},

Regards

Comment: Yes,you are right,and when i encounter the problem.I alway wonder the meaning of the report.1.Such as this time,can you tell me what's the meaning of the {conn_state,unsafe,master,"user"} ,the meaning of the conn_state,,the meaning of the unsafe,the meaning of the master ???2.And where can i find such meaning of the report?www.erlang.org????

Comment: Read de mongodb-erlang driver source code to know de meaning of diferent parameters.